# Jquery load external file that relies on jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, load

I have a set of jqueryui tabs that, when clicked, load in their content dynamically.  It works great, except that one of the pages uses a jquery plugin itself.  This results in two issues:

1. The main page that holds the tabs throws an error when loaded because there is js that refers to elements that haven't loaded yet (those elements are in the external file that contains the code that relies on the plugin).
2. If I embed the js that triggers the plugin functionality into the external file, it is outside of the document.ready function from the main page and therefore isn't usable.

Basically I am looking for a technique that allows me to ajax load an external html file into the DOM while not crapping out the main page itself because JS that is already there is expecting HTML which is not yet there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate your jquery code inside of the `$(document).ready()` function. If you're saying the code that's waiting to load via AJAX may or may not be loading at the same time as the parent page (i.e. a user has to click the tab to load it, vs. it being the default load) then you're design is bad and you'll have to rethink the approach. Basically you can't have code in your parent page referencing DOM elements that don't yet exist, and may not exist until your user clicks a tab.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet, but I think that this is what you are looking for

[Listen](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Listen)

> This plugin brings a clean, light solution, to websites with dynamic loaded content, or full of event bindings.
>   Intead of bound, handlers for events, are registered along with matching selectors.
>   And they'll still work for new added content.
>   This is achieved, using Event delegation, so the plugin will only work for events that bubble